# About pattern attribute . Wanted to know more about it

Tags: html

So I came across with the pattern attribute on Google but the information on w3schools isn't clear enough for a newbie like me.

```
pattern="[0]{1}[0-9]{7,10}"
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this means the 1st value must be a 0; the rest of the value can be any number between 0-9; the total length must be between minimum 8 to maximum 11 letters; numbers only.

```
pattern="[0-9]{5}"
```

I think this means numbers only; the total length must be 5.

I see some uses `/` at the beginning and at the end. What does that meant? There are much more to weird pattern attribute showing around here and I can't list most of them because I had no idea what it is.

Besides, if I have 2 password inputs (one for password and the other to confirm it), how do I use pattern attribute to make sure the confirm password is equals to the previous html5 password?

Comment: this looks like a regex. There are plenty of site that will explain it to you better then w3schools. Here is an example : http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: First all, that's one of the reasons why you shouldn't use W3Schools for learning. Secondly, did you even try to Google this? There are plenty of good resources out there to help newbies understand the `pattern` attribute, for example: http://html5pattern.com/

Comment: Just a note: w3schools isn't affiliated nor has any relation to W3 Consortium. See [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). Moreover, [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretations of the two `pattern` attributes are correct. The first of them is unnecessarily complicated, however. Repeating a character exactly one time means just havig it there, so the first attribute can be simplified to `pattern="0[0-9]{7,10}"`.

The slash `/` has no special meaning inside a `pattern` attribute value; it stands for itself. For example, `pattern="/\d+"` means that the value must consist of the `/` character followed by one or more digits.

The [`pattern`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) attribute is defined in HTML5 drafts so that its value follows JavaScript (ECMAScript) regular expression syntax and semantics. In practice, you should probably start from [MDN info on regexps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

You cannot use the `pattern` attribute to check that the value of a field equals the value of another field. The attribute always works on a single element. Such equality checks can easily be made with JavaScript. They should be treated as user convenience only; the real verification and protection must be made in the server-side form handler.